# Form action submit in ajax and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have created 3 radio buttons:

`Change Password - Change Name - Delete Account`

When I select one of them it shows me a form that does something... but the problem is when I started to click submit button on the showing form it redirects me to another page, not the page I selected on action property in form

**For example:**

```
    <form action = 'forget_pass.php' method = 'POST'>
```

when I click on submit button it should redirect me to page `(forget_pass.php)` but it redirects me to another page on my big project that I am working on currently.

**My code that contains radio buttons:**

```
<script>
function showUser(str) {
if (str == "") {
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "";
return;
} else { 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","get_form.php?z="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
}
</script>

<form class = "form-horizontal">

<label><p style="color:red;">
<input type = "radio" name = "select" value = "pass"      onChange="showUser(this.value)"> Change Password

<input type = "radio" name = "select" value = "name" onChange="showUser(this.value)"> Change Name

<input type = "radio" name = "select" value = "account" onChange="showUser(this.value)"> Delete Account
</p></label>

</form>
<div id = "results"> </div>
```

My code that showing the forms(get_form.php):

```
<?php
$z = $_GET['z'];
if($z == "pass")
{
   // form 
}
else if ($z == "account")
{
   // form
}

else if($z == "name")
{
   // form
}
?>
```

Comment: The code works perfectly, so the problem should be in another place.

Comment: I finally found what is going ... the code was pretty good and very fine ... i just forget to write 'forget_pass.php' in good way ... problem was in case sensitive letters .. i wrote it `forge_pass.php` instead of `forget_pass.php` ... i am so sorry about this ... but anyway ... just consider my code a knowledge for other programmers.

Comment: Don't worry, it happens ;)